# Most efficient way to create matrix of averages

Tags: r, matrix

Very basic question here!  On a 10 x 2 data frame, I want to calculate the average of each column and place the result in a new 1 x 2 matrix.

`colmeans` calculates the averages, but places the result in a 2 x 1 vector.
Attempting to transpose the vector gives error message "Error in transpose(AverageX) : l must be a list."

As a workaround, I created an empty 1 x 2 matrix (filled with NAs), then used `rbind` to merge the Averages vector with the empty matrix, and then deleted the NAs.

It works but I bet could do the same with two lines of code rather than four. Would anyone have a better way to achieve this? Thanks very much for the help.

```
df <- data.frame(Price = c(1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205), XXX = c( 1218, 1218, 1219, 1218, 1221,  1217 , 1217, 1216, 1219, 1216))

Average <- colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE) #result is a vector => turn it into a 1xm matrix
AverageMatrix <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
AverageMatrix <- rbind(AverageMatrix, Average)
AverageMatrix<- AverageMatrix[-1, , drop = FALSE]
```

EDIT:
@akrun creating a matrix of averages and creating an average for each column of a matrix are similar yet technically different issues, hence in my opinion this is not a duplicate. The question expresses that I already knew how to calculate an average for each column of a matrix, and that I wanted a more efficient way to store that result as a matrix, a simple issue that is not addressed in the other question.

Comment: matrix(Average, nrow = 1, ncol = 2) ?

Comment: Or `matrix(colmeans(df), 1, 2)`. Note that vectors do not have dimension in R.

Comment: `Average <- t(t(colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)))` ?

Comment: Thank you all very much `t(colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE))` replicates my 4 lines of code in 1, exactly what I needed. Prefer it to the Allan T answer as it is simpler. Want to put it in as a reponse so I may mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a named matrix of column means by simply transposing the result from `colMeans()`, because (from `help(t)`)

> When x is a vector, it is treated as a column, i.e., the result is a 1-row matrix.

```
t(colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE))
#       Price    XXX
# [1,] 1214.4 1217.9
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`, we can loop through the columns and get the `mean` (after converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE)]
#   Price    XXX
#1: 1214.4 1217.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I use dplyr for stuff like this. Using dplyr you can:

```
df <- data.frame(Price = c(1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205), XXX = c( 1218, 1218, 1219, 1218, 1221,  1217 , 1217, 1216, 1219, 1216))

library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% summarize(mean(Price), mean(XXX))
res
#  mean(Price) mean(XXX)
#1      1214.4    1217.9
```

Edit: I forgot you wanted it as a matrix:

```
res <- df %>% summarize(mean(Price), mean(XXX)) %>% as.matrix
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AllanT. Prefer the columns to not change names, and actually am applying this on hundreds of columns, hence will be using one of the other answers. Very useful nonetheless..